# How to fit a simple count time series INAR(1) model

Tags: r, time-series, count-data, intervention-analysis

I am trying to perform a simple time series analysis with count time series data. My data is a sequence of small integer values like 0,1,2 and 3. I learned from various sources that INAR model would be appropriate with such data.

My question is whether anyone knows R codes for fitting a simple INAR(1) model (regressing time series data on a binary dummy variable).

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

For count time series data you can also fit Autoregressive Conditional Poisson model. Here is a link to an [article](http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/8113/) describing it. There is also an R package [acp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acp/). I used it recently and I got some decent results.

Comment: is the ACP model equivalent to the INAR model?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the LaplacesDemon package?  They have some examples for autoregressive poisson.  http://cran.cermin.lipi.go.id/web/packages/LaplacesDemon/vignettes/Examples.pdf